# Access data from Cassandra by using Spring-cloud-dataflow

Tags: cassandra, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am new in Spring and Cassandra.
I want to access data from Cassandra. Is there any kind of API what we will need? And is it opensource/free or paid?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring Data for Apache Cassandra](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-cassandra). Beforehand I would suggest some Cassandra trainings - [Datastax](https://academy.datastax.com/) has some (really) good free videos.

Comment: Thanks ! 
Is Cassandra completely open source or does it require any third party Jar/lib with commercial licence?

Comment: And Is it possible to encrypt data in Cassandra without including encryption key in project.

Comment: Apache Cassandra is completely open source and you can use it. Regarding encryption of data at rest: as from Cassandra 3.4, encryption of hints ([CASSANDRA-11040](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11040)) and encryption of commit logs ([CASSANDRA-6018](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6018)) are supported. There is also encryption of SSTables ([CASSANDRA-9633](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9633)), but is still work in progress. If you need encryption of the whole data, you will need to use the Datastax distribution.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Or I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Yes @Horia, your answer is helpful for me. Thanks!